# Does Icefaces 1.8 override window.onbeforeunload javascript event?

Tags: javascript, icefaces-1.8

I am trying to ask the user if he is sure he wants to leave by using the window.onbeforeunload  javascript event. While this works in a standalone html, when I use this in my project, which uses icefaces 1.8, it does not work. The alert box does not show up. While debugging the JS, I can see the control going back to icefaces. Is it safe to assume that icefaces is somehow overriding this? Also, more importantly, is there a way around this?

Here is the standalone JS that works.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() { 
   return 'You may lose unsaved data. Are you sure you want to leave this page? '
} 
);
</script>

<body>
<a href="http://google.com">google</a>
```

Comment: Do you receive any messages in the console?

Comment: @MatthiasWegtun the console is clear. no messages.

Answer (score 0):

Since there are no errors, maybe trying it a different appraoch will help.

since you are using 1.10 the unload() should be supported (1.8+ )

```
$(window).on('unload', function(){
    return 'You may lose unsaved data. Are you sure you want to leave this page? '
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/unload/